# What to look for when renting a lens for the solar eclispe

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount

I'm doing research on renting a lens for my camera, it's a Canon Rebel T4i for the solar eclipse. What do I look for to see if a lens can be mounted to my camera. I'm thinking of getting a Canon 100-400mm f/4.5-5.6L IS II but is should I also get an extender and if so, which one mounts to the lens and my camera.

Comment: What research have you done around lens/camera compatibility, and around lens/teleconverter compatibility?

Comment: What focal length do you want for the eclipse? Do you want to get the large eclipse disk and "diamond ring"? Or do you want to get the corona as well? There are several eclipse-dedicated sites out there, that go into precisely what focal lengths you need, depending on camera sensor size, what you're trying to capture, etc.

Comment: @scottbb please list the sites.

Comment: @osullic I’ve never done a lens rental before so this is my first. Just need to know what type of lens to look for. The one on my camera are EFS if that matters

Comment: @GregorySchultz Google is better for that than me. But starting with [Mr. Eclipse](https://www.mreclipse.com/SEphoto/SEphoto.html), even you don't read any other sites, will teach you _a lot_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the moon taken with a 400mm (Sigma 120-400mm) with a 1.4 extender (so 560mm total) on an APS-C camera (Canon 70D).

[image]

This is the complete image, no cropping (just scaling), so you can see how much the moon fills the frame and since the sun and the moon are about the same size during the eclipse, you can figure out if the corona fits.

Remarks:

- Use a decent tripod, and a remote trigger, and the mirror lockup, if supported by your camera.
- The moon and the sun move by their diameter in a couple of minutes. This is quite fast, prepare to realign often.
- You risk [destroying your shiny new and expensive lens unless you use the proper solar filter](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/09/rental-camera-gear-destroyed-by-the-solar-eclipse-of-2017/).

About extenders:

- To be able to autofocus, the camera need a lens that opens wide enough. In theory the limit for the non-pro Canon DSLRs is f/5.6, even if f/6.3 also (barely) works.
- If you use an extender, this reduces this maximum aperture, with a 1.4X you lose one stop, with 2x you lose two stops, so a f/6.3 lens becomes a f/9 (1.4x) or f/13 (2x).
- So standard autofocus longer works.
- "LiveView" autofocus could work, but you have better test that with moon shots in advance.
- Manual focus is tricky because unless you have a very stable (i.e. expensive and heavy) tripod and head, touching the camera will make everything shake wildly in the screen.
- The small apertures put you in the [diffraction-limited territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system#Digital_photography), so you have a bigger image, but not as sharp.
- Lens manufacturers design extenders for their lenses, and their lenses for their extenders. The only exception I know is Kenko (because they don't make lenses, just extenders). You can't mix brands and expect good results (especially if the lens is a zoom).
- The extended focal lens makes the sun and moon move even faster across the frame, so you will fiddle more often with the tripod and head, leading to more shake.

TL;DR: if you have a 600mm, use it as it is, don't put an extender on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After doing some research, it turns out EF lens can't be mounted on my camera as it takes EF-S lenes.

Comment: All the EF lenses fit the EF-S mount. It is the opposite which is not true (EF-S lens on EF camera). I use my 70D (and previously my 450D) with many EF lenses (Canon 100m macro, Sigma 120-400mm, Canon 50mm STM...). And I also have EF-S lenses on the same camera (60mm macro,  Sigma 17-70mm)

Comment: They won't hit the mirror when flipping? That's good to know.

Comment: They works very well. The EF-S mount is essentially an EF mount with an index that makes it incompatible with the full-frame bodies. The real difference between EF and EF-S is that EF-S lenses can have a smaller "image circle" because the sensor is smaller, so they can be made smaller/more economical.

Comment: It is amazing that to test for the solar eclipse you can use one of the models themselves!

Comment: What model is the telephoto extender? I'm assuming they work on non-Canon lenses as I found a Tamron SP 150-600mm f/5-6.3 Di VC lens available for rent.

Comment: My extender is the Sigma one, designed to work with Sigma lenses. See augmented answer about extenders. Train in advance with the moon. Other good targets for test shots are Jupiter and its 4 satellites and Saturn and its rings, doable with a 600mm. Also, last thing I forgot, get a remote trigger (or learn how to use your camera with the phone app if it supports it).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Practice on the sun. You're going to need a solar filter to capture all of the eclipse other than totality, anyway [and if you wait until totality begins to point your lens anywhere near the sun you're not going to have time to aim and focus before totality is over]. Things happen *very* fast during an eclipse. Learning ahead of time how fast the sun moves across the sly when using long focal lengths is crucial, as is learning how to focus manually even though the lens will vibrate each time you touch it. It can be done, it just takes practice (and time for smaller and smaller adjustments).

Comment: @xenoid I think a Kenko 2X Teleplus Pro 300 DGX + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II did a decent enough job with the Moon and Jupiter in [this shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZF1p.jpg). A 100% crop of [Jupiter in another shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbcio.jpg) from the same session using the same setup doesn't look too shabby, either, considering Jupiter was only about 44 arcseconds wide at the time. Both are single frames (no stacking). Seeing was excellent that night.

Comment: Yes, but that's a prime 400mm f/4, and OP is aiming a 900mm f/13 zoom. So you are confirming what I say, better a short good lens than a long bad one.